# Java binary search, high values throw exception

Tags: java, search, binary, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm trying to implement a recursive binary search, after looking at the example on [this](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c9/s1.html) textbook page.

My algorithm seems to work fine in most cases, but on values higher than the highest value in the array, I get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Looking at my algorithm and the textbook example, they seem identical; can someone help me find where I've gone wrong?

I'm aware this is mostly the same issue as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017097/java-recursive-binary-search-throwing-out-of-bounds-exception), and I have already considered the solution it proposes. The example code however, does not implement any argument correction like this, and I wonder why it works without it.

```
    public static int binarySearch(int[] array, int item, int lowPos, int highPos){
    if (lowPos > highPos){
        return -1;
    }

    int mid = (lowPos + highPos)/2;

    if (array[mid] == item){
        return mid;
    }else if (array[mid] > item){
        return binarySearch(array, item, lowPos, mid-1);
    }else{
        return binarySearch(array, item, mid+1, highPos);
    }
}
```

This is the textbook example, which obviously does not produce the error:

```
    static int binarySearch(int[] A, int loIndex, int hiIndex, int value) {

   if (loIndex > hiIndex) {
         // The starting position comes after the final index,
         // so there are actually no elements in the specified
         // range.  The value does not occur in this empty list!
      return -1;
   }

   else {
         // Look at the middle position in the list.  If the
         // value occurs at that position, return that position.
         // Otherwise, search recursively in either the first
         // half or the second half of the list.
      int middle = (loIndex + hiIndex) / 2;
      if (value == A[middle])
         return middle;
      else if (value < A[middle])
         return binarySearch(A, loIndex, middle - 1, value);
      else   // value must be > A[middle]
         return binarySearch(A, middle + 1, hiIndex, value);
   }

} // end binarySearch()
```

Comment: What exception do you get? Can you post the stacktrace?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza He says he gets an out of bounds exception.

Comment: Cannot replicate the behavior. Could you post the error-inducing code (too lazy too try to go through it)? I am thinking you might have put the wrong arguments there.

Comment: The only thing I can get is that you're sending the parameters in the wrong way. Note that book method uses array, low index, high index and value, while your method uses array, **value**, low index, high index. This means, when calling the `binarySearch` method from your client class/method e.g. `public static void main(String[] args)`.

Comment: OP, would you please put us out our misery and let us know who is right? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is fine, you are just passing in values incorrectly.  You are probably using the wrong highPos to start your method, if that is the case use myArray.length -1 as opposed to myArray.length.

Otherwise you are calling the arguments completely wrong for your revised method, possibly switching the values.  The calling code should look like the following.

```
binarySearch(myArray, myIntToSearchFor, 0, myArray.length-1)
```

Comment: That is most likely the issue. However, are you looking through a magic glass since I don't see the calling code posted (or maybe "you might be passing")? If you are right, kudos for random guessing.

Comment: The code is correct, so process of elimination

Comment: I don't think so. Refer to my last comment on OP's question. By the way, I wonder how did you eliminate something that you never saw before :).

Comment: But he properly switches how he calls the method to account for that.  So that is not the issue.  The code is good, his calling of the method is not

Comment: Only inside the method, we're not sure about the client class/method that consumes this `binarySearch` method :). Of course, this is the result of copy / lazy paste without thinking on the consequences of my new code.

Comment: You're right, that is the other possible explanation, so I revised my answer to reflect that.  But the issue is definitely is how he is calling the method, not the method code itself.

Comment: Next time when you want to reply a comment use `@<username>` to notify the user about the reply :). Removed my downvote.

Comment: Now I feel stupid, this was indeed the problem :)

This was my function call:

int[] hey = new int[] { 2,54,200,430,1000,1002,1003,1006,3000 };
  System.out.println(binarySearch(hey, 1000, 0, hey.length));


When I got the exception, I tried running the textbook method with the same arguments, and did not account for the different signature.

Thanks a lot everyone!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are passing `array.length` instead of `array.length - 1` as the argument to `highPos`.